# Custom function in R with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to write a custom function for R which has elements of dplyr in it.

The first part went well. I made a function, `value_count` that creates a frequency distribution table for any column in a specified data frame:

```
value_count = function(data, group_col) {
data %>% 
group_by_(.dots = lazyeval::lazy(group_col)) %>% 
summarize(count=n())
```

Here's an example of the output:

```
colour  count
green    10
red      8
blue     2
```

Now, in the same function, I want to add a "percent" column that calculates the % of people who choose each colour. Like this:

```
colour  count   percent
green    10       50
red      8        40
blue     2        10
```

To do so, I tried this function:

```
value_count2 = function(data, group_col) {
data %>% 
group_by_(.dots = lazyeval::lazy(group_col)) %>% 
summarize(count=n()) %>% 
mutate(percent = count/(sum(count)) * 100)
}
```

But I get this error:

```
"Error: Problem adding computed columns in `group_by()`.
x Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
```

I've tested this outside of creating a function (i.e. manually performing `group_by(group_col) %>% summarize(count=n()) %>% mutate(percent = count/(sum(count)) * 100)` on the same dataset) and everything works perfectly :-S

Any idea what is occurring? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since functions with `_` (like `group_by_`, `count_` etc) are deprecated, you can use -

```
library(dplyr)

value_count <- function(data, group_col) {
  data %>%
    count({{group_col}}, name = 'count') %>%
    mutate(count = prop.table(count) * 100)
}

value_count(data, colour)
```

Comment: Cool. I didn't know that - thanks. And also this seems to work perfectly!

Comment: @Ronak Shah. Why do you think is the test with mtcars in my answer is working without double curly brackets? Thank you!

Comment: I think that is because of `lazyeval::lazy` which works similar to curly curly.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo `mutate_` should be `mutate`

```
value_count2 = function(data, group_col) {
    data %>% 
        group_by_(.dots = lazyeval::lazy(group_col)) %>% 
        summarize(count=n()) %>% 
        mutate(percent = count/(sum(count)) * 100)
}
```

Test with `mtcars`:

```
value_count2 = function(data, group_col) {
    data %>% 
        group_by_(.dots = lazyeval::lazy(group_col)) %>% 
        summarize(count=n()) %>% 
        mutate(percent = count/(sum(count)) * 100)
}

value_count2(mtcars, cyl)
```

output:

```
    cyl count percent
  <dbl> <int>   <dbl>
1     4    11    34.4
2     6     7    21.9
3     8    14    43.8
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it's just a typo in the question I wrote, though. In my original code "mutate" was also written without an underscore (I've fixed it in the question now). I still get the error, which makes me think it's something about my original dataset. Will take a look further...